# Heroku and Route 53

Tags: heroku, dns

My registrar is godaddy and I run my app on Heroku. I would like to use Route 53 to point to my apps.

Since heroku doesn't recommend A names that point to their proxy, what is the setup I should use? (Or what is the recommended way of setting this up. I do not want to use SimpleDNS, which they talk about in the heroku tutorials).

Thank you,

Answer (score 7):

I just finished writing the [Naked Domain section of the Heroku docs on Amazon Route 53](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53#nakedroot-domain). This explains how to set up at 302 redirect from **example.com** to **www.example.com** using Amazon S3 and Route 53.

Comment: Hi @dustin-hoffman, since it appears you wrote that section I have a question for you: Your description in the Heroku docs of how the ALIAS record works, and Route 53's description of their ALIAS record appear to differ. Could you elaborate on this? Heroku docs say it is a 302 redirect, however Route 53 says it is an actual IP proxy. See there docs here: http://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/#Supported_DNS_record_types

Comment: Have you found a way to remove the "www" completely using route53 and heroku?

Comment: @ChrisFoster sorry for the late response. I don't know the reason for the discrepancy. I have simply seen the ALIAS S3 static site perform 302's to get me from mydomain.com to www.mydomain.

Comment: @chrishough this is impossible because Heroku needs flexibility in their dyno IP assignments. Even SSL dynos with "static" IPs can change. So, no, there is no way to rely on an A record with Heroku.

Comment: Thanks for the write up. Super useful!

Comment: AWS has updated their website and this guide feels quite out of date. Hard to follow for someone inexperienced with aws like myself. For example, I don't see a "pre-populated Delegation Set section in the sidebar"

Comment: The linked article does not address https for the root domain redirect

Answer (score 1):

First you should transfer your DNS to Amazon Route 53. After that you create a CNAME with your-app.herokuapp.com.

You should also add the domain name pointing to your heroku instance on the app's setting page  under the "Domains".

After that it should work.

Comment: It seems Route 53 now supports apex domains, meaning can have both mysite.com and www.mysite.com pointing to your heroku app.

Comment: Can you describe how to setup an apex domain that points to Heroku in Route 53?

Comment: @Dustin Hoffman's solution is the correct one. Route53 does *not* allow apex CNAME: "RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name yourdomain.com. is not permitted at apex in zone yourdomain.com."

Comment: You can only have an apex domain on Route53 if it's pointing at a service hosted by AWS

Comment: sorry can someone confirm when you transfer your domain to aws you still need a dns service like dnssimple to use route53 with heroku. thanks

Comment: @birmacher I did the same what you said, however, I see that my domain name failed. what can be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

[Heroku's basic recommendation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/route-53) will redirect to the http version of the site even if you open https. So it's basically useless.

Ideally you want all of the following URLs to resolve to the same place:

- http://example.com
- https://example.com
- http://www.example.com
- https://www.example.com

For [technical reasons](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/apex-domains), DNS CNAME records (sometimes called ALIAS or ANAME) should be preferred over A records to point to the root (sometimes called apex/bare/naked) domains. While [some providers](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain) support this, AWS Route 53 does not.

Therefore an ideal AWS setup routes all the above to https://www.example.com.

This can be done at no extra cost but requires some extra pieces of infrastructure (~15 min setup). Unless noted use default config.

**1, S3 Bucket to redirect to `www.` subdomain**

- Create a S3 Static Hosting Website and have it redirect to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).
- Use `https` protocol.

**2, SSL certificate in Certificate Manager**

- Create for both example.com and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

**3, CloudFront distribution**

- Use 'Redirect HTTP to HTTPS'
- As origin use the full domain of the S3 bucket. Do not select the bucket from the lsit but use the actual domain. E.g. `example.com.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`
- For Alternate Domain Names provide example.com
- Provide SSL certificates created previously

**4, DNS record in Route53**

- A Alias record of example.com pointing to CloudFront
- CNAME record of [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) pointing to Heroku (*.herokudns.com)

Comment: The issue I run into using this approach is that http://www.example.com will not redirect to https://www.example.com.
All other urls will result in https://www.example.com.